# Android: how to get a list of Panoramio/Google maps photos in ceratin?

Tags: android, gps, maps, panoramio

I'm developing an application which includes processing of Panoramio/Google maps photos around user location. It uses images, coordinates and description of photos.
What way is most convinient for obtaining such info?

Thanks forward for help!

Answer (score 1):

Panoramio offers an API with multiple possibilities to obtain images and descriptions. You can have a look there:

http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html

Comment: Thanks, I saw this API description, hope maybe some other library exists without need of parsing html/json

Comment: Almost any modern programming language provides libraries and functions to parse xml and json. That should not be a problem.